# javax.crypto AES encryption - Do I only need to call doFinal?

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I want to do AES CBC encryption in Java.  I'm using `javax.crypto`. After I have the `Cipher` initialized, do I only need to call `doFinal` on the clear bytes to properly encrypt it?  Or do I need to do something with `update`?

Documentation says update:

> Continues a multiple-part encryption
>   or decryption operation

and doFinal

> Encrypts or decrypts data in a
>   single-part operation, or finishes a
>   multiple-part operation

what exactly do they mean by multiple-part encryption?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

doFinal adds the PKCS7 [padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29#CBC_mode) in the last block. So you can call update zero to many times, but last call should be an doFinal. Multipart encryption is when the data is not contiguous in memory. Typical example being buffers received from a socket. You set up the cipher and then start calling update to encrypt or decrypt the data, block by block, and build up the encrypted/decrypted data, by appending the blocks returned by update. On last input block you call doFinal and the returned block is the last one to be appended to the output data. On ecnrypting, doFinal will add the padding. On decrypting doFinal will validate and remove the padding.

Comment: So do I have to separate my byte array into chunks of BLOCKSIZE size and call update on each block except the last one, and call doFinal on the last one?  Or can I just call doFinal on the whole thing and it will do it all for me?

Comment: You only need to do multiple updates if the data is not contiguous. If you already have it in a single contiguous block, you can just call doFinal once.

Comment: Ahh, I see.  So the reason you would do encryption as multipart is because you want to get started encrypting data as soon as you receive it rather than waiting until you fully receive all the data?

Comment: Right. also you don't want to move data around just to create a contiguous block.